# FormArray dentro FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de crear un FormArray dentro otro FormArray pero no lo consigo, anteriormente si lo lograba pero me marcaba errores ahorita ya no me marca ningun error, pero no me crea los campos que le indico, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

En mi componente lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
formNewProduct = this.formBuilder.group({
    code: ['', Validators.required],
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    infoProduct: this.formBuilder.array([this.newInfo])
  })

  get newInfo(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      size: this.formBuilder.array([this.newSize]),
      description: [''],
      color: [''],
      // stock: [''],
      price: [''],
      image: [''],
    })
  }

  get infos(): FormArray {
    return this.formNewProduct.get('infoProduct') as FormArray;
  }

  addInfos() {
    this.infos.push(this.newInfo);
  }

  removeInfos(i: number) {
    this.infos.controls.splice(i, 1);
    this.infos.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  get newSize(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      size: [''],
      color: [''],
      stock: [''],
    })
  }

  get sizes(): FormArray {
    return this.newInfo.get('size') as FormArray;
  }

  addSizes() {
    this.sizes.push(this.newSize);
  }

  removeSizes(i: number) {
    this.sizes.controls.splice(i, 1);
    this.sizes.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

En mi HTML si se estra creando todo correctamente

```
<fieldset formArrayName="infoProduct" class="mb-3">

    <div class="row">

      <fieldset class="col-md-12" name="size" *ngFor="let info of infos.controls; let i = index"
        style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">

        <div formArrayName="size" class="mb-3">

          <fieldset class="col-md-12" name="size" *ngFor="let zise of sizes.controls; let i = index"
            style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" placeholder="Tamaño"
                  formControlName="size" />

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="Stock"
                formControlName="stock" />

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="removeSizes(i)">

                <mdb-icon fas icon="minus-circle"></mdb-icon>Eliminar

              </a>

            </div>

          </fieldset>

          <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="addSizes()">

            <mdb-icon far icon="plus-square"></mdb-icon>Agregar

          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" data="data" formControlName="description">
          </ckeditor>

          <!-- <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Descripcion"
              cols="30" rows="4" formControlName="description"></textarea> -->

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

            <color-circle formControlName="color"></color-circle>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Precio"
              formControlName="price" />

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image"
            (change)="cargarImagen($event, i)" />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="removeInfos(i)">

            <mdb-icon fas icon="minus-circle"></mdb-icon>Eliminar

          </a>

        </div>

        <hr>

      </fieldset>

    </div>

    <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="addInfos()">

      <mdb-icon far icon="plus-square"></mdb-icon>Agregar

    </a>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar a entender que estoy haciendo mal y cual deberia ser la manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poniéndole los paréntesis a `newInfo` porque es una función:

```
infoProduct: this.formBuilder.array([this.newInfo()])
```